# How to @Inject an interface in @HiltViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am trying to run the following pieces of code.

My ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashModel @Inject constructor(private val preferenceRep: PreferenceRep) : ViewModel() {

    private val _intoEvent = EventLiveData<Unit>()
    val intoEvent = _intoEvent.asLiveData()

    private val _homeEvent = EventLiveData<Unit>()
    val homeEvent = _homeEvent.asLiveData()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val isFirstTime = preferenceRep.isFirstTime().awaitValueOrError()
            delay(800L)
            if (isFirstTime)
                _intoEvent post EventUnit
            else
                _homeEvent post EventUnit
        }
    }
}
```

My Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

    private val splashModel by viewModels<SplashModel>()

    private val binding get() = splash!!
    private var splash: FragmentSplashBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        splash = FragmentSplashBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        splashModel.intoEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
            navigate(R.id.nav_intro)
        })
        splashModel.homeEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
            navigate(R.id.nav_home)
        })
    }

    private fun navigate(id: Int) {
        findNavController().apply {
            popBackStack()
            navigate(id)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        splash = null
    }
}
```

My App class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application() {}
```

My Preference Repository:

```
interface PreferenceRep {
    fun isFirstTime(): FlowResult<Boolean>
}
```

My Impl of Preference:

```
class PreferenceRepImpl @Inject constructor(private val dao: PreferenceDao) : PreferenceRep {

    override fun isFirstTime(): FlowResult<Boolean> {
        return dao.isFirstTime()
            .map { SuccessResult(it) }
            .catch { ErrorResult(RepositoryException(it)) }
    }
}
```

My PreferenceDao:

```
interface PreferenceDao {
    fun isFirstTime(): Flow<Boolean>
}
```

My Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class PreferenceModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    abstract fun preferenceDao(daoImpl: PreferenceDaoImpl): PreferenceDao

}
```

My PreferenceDaoImpl:

```
class PreferenceDaoImpl @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) : PreferenceDao {

    private val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val flowPref = FlowSharedPreferences(preferences)

    override fun isFirstTime(): Flow<Boolean> {
        return flowPref.boolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME, true).asFlow()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_FIRST_TIME = "KEY_FIRST_TIME"
    }
}
```

And the exception:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.preferences.PreferenceRep cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements App_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.preferences.PreferenceRep is injected at
          xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.models.SplashModel(preferenceRep)
      xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.models.SplashModel is injected at
          xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.models.SplashModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.App_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.App_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.App_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

I searched for a solution, but did not find anything how to deal with annotations within the `PreferenceRep` interface. By the way I am trying to get it done like in this sample project: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples but using Dagger Hilt.

Comment: where is the implementation of `PreferenceRep` and the module where you provide/bind interface to implementation which I assume is "installed" in the SingletonComponent?

Comment: @MarkKeen Thanks for your reply. I added the missing info to the question. Please take a look in. Thanks!

Comment: That module is for PreferenceDao, which should have `@Binds` not `@Provides` - you need to also bind `PreferenceRepImpl` to `PreferenceRep` in the same module. The `PreferenceRep` interface seems pointless, how is it a repository contract with a method called : `fun isFirstTime(): FlowResult<Boolean>` seems pointless (bad) abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a look in. But I think, using Hilt is not really productive. It takes to much time to build the project and if there is another syntax issue or whatever, what is not the problem of Hilt the IDE does not show you the problem, only the build failure and that's all.

Comment: Hilt is an extension of Dagger2 (it removes some boilerplate code by wiring up "stuff" through annotations) - if you aren't familiar with Dagger2 this then all the benefits of Hilt are lost when you enter Dagger specific issues.  If you are creating a small application then the cost of setting up DI might not be worth it.  If this is a production app then a dependency library is usually something worth using.